# "node filename.js" is not working in vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I created a hello.js file in vs code containing a `console.log` , and when I type in the terminal `node hello.js` I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

The content of my js file:

```
console.log("hello");
```

Is it because vs code? Should I use another IDE?

UPDATE: The problem also persists with Node.js Command Prompt
UPDATE2: I created the same file again with Sublime Text instead of VS Code and it works.. it was probably a bug from VS Code

Comment: Have you tried to run it from command line?

Comment: you should try `node ./hello.js` instead, but anyhow please update your question with the full `hello.js` file, even though "it's just a `console.log`". ;)

Comment: Have you tried to run `node --version` in the vscode terminal and outside it? Which terminal is selected in vscode?

Comment: Maybe you have a weird invisible first char, such as utf BOM...

Answer (score 0):

Where's your hello.js file code? Did you have the proper code?

Example:

hello.js file (make sure you save the file):

```
console.log('Hello')
```

Open terminal in vs code (visual studio code), or hotkey press ctrl + ` (this ` key is next to number 1 on your keyboard), or go to top menu View > Terminal.

Type node hello

It will output: Hello

Comment: It's saved, and it still throws me that error. My hello.js file is in D:\Sublime Text 3\npm\directory and I made sure that I was inside that directory when I ran node hello.js

Comment: console.log("hello");

Comment: Did you open terminal as I showed you? Make sure you're in the correct folder path.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Command Prompt]

Your code is perfect it's run fine, I think your node in not install properly you cna check it run another js file like this.